# Why it gives invalid constant value?

Tags: flutter, dart

int _selectedIndex = 0; - is a variable defined in this state class so why there is an error?

[image]

```
Compiler message:
lib/rappport_list.dart:139:29: Error: Not a constant expression.
                            _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.red : Colors.cyan,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/rappport_list.dart:139:47: Error: Not a constant expression.
                            _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.red : Colors.cyan,
                                              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Because it’s not a constant. Why did you write `const`?

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did not wrire `const`, why did you decide so?

Comment: It says `const TextStyle`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Dart when you pass something as a `parameter` in a `const` constructor, the compiler makes sure that the value set as `default` is not changed during the execution of the code.

Hence, the "Invalid constant value" warning.

To resolve this issue you should **remove the `const` keyword** from the in front of the **`TextStyle`**.

Answer (score 4):

`const TextStyle` is expecting all the members it is using to be **constant**, Either remove `const` ahead of `TextStyle` or define `_selectedIndex` as const, which I don't think will be feasible for you as the name suggests. So better remove the `const` ahead of `TextStyle`.